# Traefik doen't route to the appropriate container

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to use traefik with my docker containers for routing.

File structure is:

```
docker
├── docker-compose.yml
├── shared
│   └── .htpasswd
└── traefik
    ├── acme
    │   └── acme.json
    ├── rules.toml
    └── traefik.toml
```

Here is traefik.toml:

```
logLevel = "ERROR"
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

[web]
address = ":8080"
  [web.auth.basic]
  usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

# Force HTTPS
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[file]
  watch = true
  filename = "/etc/traefik/rules.toml"

[acme]
email = "test@test.com"
storage="/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
acmeLogging=true
onDemand = false #create certificate when container is created
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "digitalocean"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "test.com"
[[acme.domains]]
   main = "*.test.com"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "test.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  traefik:
    hostname: traefik
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      #- "8080:8080"
    environment:
      #- digitalocean=${DO_AUTH_TOKEN}
      - DO_AUTH_TOKEN=${DO_AUTH_TOKEN}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAINNAME}"
#      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}; PathPrefixStrip: /traefik"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik:/etc/traefik
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external:
      name: traefik_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

After running traefik container I'm trying to create another one from the repository:

```
docker run -d \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --label traefik.backend=hello-hapi \
  --label traefik.frontend.rule=Host:hello-hapi.test.com \
  --label traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy \
  --label traefik.port=80 \
  --name hello_hapi \
  gitlab.test.com:5555/myuser/hello_hapi:latest
```

The problem is that I can not access the container through the browser. It prints: `hello-hapi.test.com’s server IP address could not be found (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)`.
But the image can be seen in the traefik dashboard and
`docker run -it -p 3000:3000 --rm gitlab.test.com:5555/myuser/hello_hapi:latest`
runs as expected on `test.com:3000`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is checking the DNS zone for "test.com" and then in that zone there is no "hello-hapi.test.com" entry.

You need to own the domain in order to add DNS entries for it. If that wasn't the case, I could have my domain as "neekoy.google.com", which Google wouldn't be particularly happy about.

If you want to access it in a browser, you can add a local DNS entry on your computer and point "test.com" to localhost(127.0.0.1). If you don't know how, you can Google "hosts file" for your operating system and add the following line in it:

127.0.0.1 hello-hapi.test.com test.com www.test.com

Comment: test.com is just for example. I'm using domain I bought.

Comment: Have you created the subdomain hello-hapi.yourdomain.com in the DNS zone for that domain?